# Summarize multiple raster layers in a multipolygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I want to calculate an ethnic fractionalization index for the second administrative division in the DRC based on the SIDE-Dataset which can be found here: https://icr.ethz.ch/data/side/.

Each layer provides information on the population share of one ethnic group, ranging from zero to one. In total 10 layers must be summarized, I thought the mean value per ethnic group per subdivision might be a good approach. Is there an efficient way to do this?